# Combine text from rows got by specified date in a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a summary sheet that combines the values and descriptions from my bank transaction into individual dates

I want to paste the transaction csv into google spreadsheets.
The columns are `Date`, `Description`, `CheckNumber` and `Amount`.

[Here is my example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KSq1-E3ONVEhG-zmDGlP-1mEDvn3w_w1O4muWxia0Bw/edit?usp=sharing)

What I want would be for `Summary!D2` to combine the description of all rows that have the date 2/1/2014 (shown in `Summary!A2`) like this (including line feeds).

**EDIT - Switched to Jacobs Method**

Final code (Removes N/A error when nothing found in query):

```
=JOIN(CHAR(10),ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(QUERY(Transactions!A2:D, "SELECT B WHERE B IS NOT NULL AND A = date '" & text(Summary!A2,"yyyy-MM-dd") & "'") & ": ") & IFERROR(QUERY(Transactions!A2:D, "SELECT D WHERE D IS NOT NULL AND A = date '" & text(Summary!A2,"yyyy-MM-dd") & "'"))))
```

**EDIT - Added amounts to lines of note**

```
PartTime Payroll: 182.7 
Academy Payroll: 81.13
Recurring purchase at netflix.com: -7.99
ONLINE TRANSFER TO CC: XXXXXXXXXX: -49
```

The values in Summary are already showing what I want, which in this case is `$206.84` which is the result of the `Amounts` with the date 2/1/2014 from `Summary!A2`, `(182.7, 81.13, -7.99, -49)`.

**EDIT - I figured it out**

---

```
function updateNote(cellDate){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sumSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var transSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Transactions');
  var transSheetLastRow = transSheet.getLastRow();

  cellDate = cellDate.valueOf();
  var currDate;
  var note;
  var text;
  var amount;
  var space = ": ";

  for (var i = 2; i < transSheetLastRow; i++){
    var currDate = transSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue().valueOf();

    if(cellDate == currDate){
      text = transSheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
      amount = transSheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue();

      if (!note){
        note = text + space + amount;
      }else{
        note = note + '\n' + text + space + amount;
      }
    }
  }
  return note;
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer. Note the added equal sign in the for loop. `for (var i = 2; i <= transSheetLastRow; i++){` It needs to be `<=`, previously it was only `<`.

Comment: Updated again, the notes weren't updating properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a formula to accomplish your goal.

### Formula

```
=JOIN(
   CHAR(10),
   ARRAYFORMULA(
     QUERY(
       Transactions!A2:D, 
       "SELECT B WHERE A = date '" & text(Summary!A2,"yyyy-MM-dd") & "'"
     ) 
     & ": " &   <=== concatenate
     QUERY(
       Transactions!A2:D, 
       "SELECT D WHERE A = date '" & text(Summary!A2,"yyyy-MM-dd") & "'"
     )
   )
 )

 copy/paste         
 =JOIN(CHAR(10),ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(Transactions!A2:D, "SELECT B WHERE A = date '" & text(Summary!A2,"yyyy-MM-dd") & "'") & ": " & QUERY(Transactions!A2:D, "SELECT D WHERE A = date '" & text(Summary!A2,"yyyy-MM-dd") & "'")))
```

### Explained

The two `QUERY` functions, both deliver each part of the data you want to present: the description and the value. These two are then "glued" together, via the ampersands and per row, via the `ARRAYFORMULA`. Each row is then joined, via the `JOIN` function, using a line feed (`CHAR(10)`) as delimiter.

### Screenshot

[image]

### Note

The huge benefit over a script is the immediate re-calculation of the data, when changes occur. Just copy the formula downwards to get all the results. You can add your own logic to remove empty fields.

### Example

I've prepare an example file for you: **[Notes](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WTLieugEcZ-7XXQPtjAU9d47ajEv9LewbS6pz15HE2w/edit?usp=sharing)**

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this with a script:

```
var transSheetName = 'Transactions';
var sumSheetName = 'Summary';

function updateNote(cellDate){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sumSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sumSheetName);
  var transSheet = ss.getSheetByName(transSheetName);
  var transSheetLastRow = transSheet.getLastRow();

  cellDate = cellDate.valueOf();
  var currDate;
  var note;
  var amount;
  var space = ': $';

  for (var i = 2; i <= transSheetLastRow; i++){
    var currDate = transSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue().valueOf();
    if(cellDate == currDate){
      amount = transSheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
      if (amount < 0){
        amount = -amount;
        space = ': -$';
      }

      if (!note){
        note = transSheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue() + space + amount;
      }else{
        note = note + '\n' + transSheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue() + space + amount;
      }
    }
  }
  return note;
}




function onEdit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var column = range.getColumn();

  if (sheet.getName() == transSheetName && row > 1){
    var date = sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue();
    var note = sheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue();
    var amount = sheet.getRange(row, 4).getValue();

    if (date != '' && note != '' && amount != ''){
      Browser.msgBox('Running...');
      //return false;
      var sumSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sumSheetName);
      var currDate = date.valueOf();
      var cellDate;
      for (var i = 2; i <= 32; i++){
        cellDate = sumSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue().valueOf();
        if (cellDate == currDate){
          sumSheet.getRange(i, 4).setFormula('=updateNote(A' + i + ', ' + transSheetName + '!B' + row + ')');
        }
      }
    }
  }


  if (sheet.getName() == sumSheetName && row == 1 && column == 1){
    var transSheet = ss.getSheetByName(transSheetName);
    var transSheetLastRow = transSheet.getLastRow();
    var i = 2;
    for (; i <= 32; i++){
      sheet.getRange(i, 4).setFormula('=updateNote(A' + i + ', ' + transSheetName + '!A' + transSheetLastRow + ':D' + transSheetLastRow + ')');
    }
  }
}
```

The script is called from the cells in the D-column. You call it with the cell containing the date on the same row as parameter. So in `D2` you write `=updateNote(A2)`, in `D3` you write `=updateNote(A3)` and so forth.

It's rather annoying having to enter the function in every cell, so I wrote a script for that too. Run it once and never again:

```
function fill(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  if(sheet.getName() == 'Summary'){
    for (var i = 2; i < 32; i++){
      sheet.getRange(i, 4).setFormula('=updateNote(A' + i + ')');
    }
  }
}
```

Copy [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m6-6EnwgttE1dKP5UBMLf7xgXDUrAuWBy0bbEWTiAKw/edit?usp=sharing) to try it.

---

**Edit**

The fill-function shouldn't be necessary anymore, just switch to another month in the summary-sheet and the `onEdit` function will fix that.

Also, [Jacob's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/58778/29712) is much faster, and after my edit even more simpler. So I'd recommend using that. (I continue editing this partly because I feel I owe you that for giving me the bounty, and partly because I enjoy coding ;)  )

Comment: This looks like it fits the bill. You definitely get the bounty. However now that I am seeing the results I am wondering, is it difficult to append the amount to the note? See modified question.

Comment: Figured it out!

Comment: Great, thank you!
I updated my code after your edit. It's quite similar to your solution, just that it includes dollar signs in the note.

Comment: -1; The total amount of notes is 8. Your summary shown only 7. In order to re-calculate, you need to add `onEdit()` functions as well, throughout the `TRANSACTIONS` sheet.

Comment: Why don't you join me in this chat room: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13056/spreadsheet-nerds

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra I found the error, I was missing an equal-sign in the for-loop-condition. It skiped the last line in the transaction sheet. Since the cells calling the script are sending a cell-reference as a parameter a `onEdit`-function should not be necessary. When passing a cell reference the function runs again as soon as the value of the passed cell is changed. As read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9023954/739534).